# CSS webkit-transform not working properly on IOS

Tags: html, ios, css

This is the css I used, it works perfectly fine on windows, android, mac etc but not working on ios. Please help me out. I am out of solutions. When I press on the menu nothing happens. I tried with both chrome and safari on iphone and then an ipad. This helped me to understand it has something to do with ios.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZRjLd

css:

```
.menu-outer:hover ~ .menu-close {
  margin-right:-100px;
}
.menu-outer:hover .bar { background:rgba(100,200,240,.9); }
.menu-outer > nav ul { top:15%; }



html, body {
  background: rgba(20,20,20,1);
}

.menu-outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', serif;
  z-index: 998;  
  width: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  height: 200%;
  background: rgba(100,200,240,.9);  
  -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
  -ms-transition: all ease .5s;
  -o-transition: all ease .5s;
  transition: all ease .5s; 
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  -o-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu-outer:hover {
  background: rgba(100,200,240,.98);
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.menu-icon {
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 30px;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
  -ms-transition: all ease .5s;
  -o-transition: all ease .5s;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
.menu-icon .bar {
  background: rgba(250,250,250,1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
  -ms-transition: all ease .5s;
  -o-transition: all ease .5s;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
.menu-outer:hover > .menu-icon {
  opacity: 0;
}
nav ul {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  padding: 0;
  left: 10%;; /*prevents possible click when not oppened*/
  -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
  -ms-transition: all ease .5s;
  -o-transition: all ease .5s;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
.menu-outer:hover > nav ul {
  left: 0;
}
nav li {
  list-style:none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav li a {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display:block;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
  -ms-transition: all ease .5s;
  -o-transition: all ease .5s;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
nav li a:hover {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px), screen and (max-height: 600px) {
  nav ul {font-size:.75em;}
  nav ul a {padding: 10px;}
}
.menu-close {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(250,130,70,1);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
  -ms-transition: all ease .5s;
  -o-transition: all ease .5s;
  transition: all ease .5s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
  -moz-transform-origin: top right;
  -ms-transform-origin: top right;
  -o-transform-origin: top right;
  transform-origin: top right;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-close .menu-icon {
  right: 15px; left: auto;top: 68px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu-close .bar {
  background: rgba(250,250,250,1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
}
.menu-close .bar:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-close .bar:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-outer">
    <div class="menu-icon">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">About</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
<a class="menu-close" onClick="return true">
    <div class="menu-icon">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I loaded the codepen on my iPad Pro and can get it to work when I touch the upper right corner of the blue triangle so it's not recognizing when you tap the hamburger menu. You may need to set the display:inline-block so it recognizes the entire area of the menu ... that's my best guess, but I can get it to work.

Comment: after you said about the upper corner, I also tried to touch there and it worked fine.